# Why does Ionic toggle switches effect one another when using Recoil?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, next.js, capacitor, recoiljs

I have two [Ionic toggle switches](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toggle) and they both effect one another when used with Recoil. When I console both of them, initially they show the correct default value but when I switch the OFF to ON, the ON switches to OFF and shows undefined in console. It's like I can't have both of them ON at the same time but can with OFF. What am I doing wrong here?

Atom.ts:

```
import { atom } from "recoil";

interface Settings {
  showCoords?: boolean;
  showAnimations?: boolean;
}

const defaultSettings: Settings = {
  showCoords: false,
  showAnimations: true,
};

export const SettingsState = atom<Settings>({
  key: "settingsState",
  default: defaultSettings,
});
```

Settings.tsx:

```
  const [mySettings, setMySettings] = useRecoilState(SettingsState);

  const thisCoords = mySettings.showCoords;
  const thisAnimations = mySettings.showAnimations;


    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Vis koordinater</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle
        id="showCoords"
        name="showCoords"
        checked={thisCoords}
        onClick={() => setMySettings({ showCoords: !thisCoords })}
      ></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Vis animationer</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle
        id="showAnimations"
        name="showAnimations"
        checked={thisAnimations}
        onClick={() => setMySettings({ showAnimations: !thisAnimations })}
      ></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using all the wrong template tags. You need to be using react style tags.

```
 <IonItem>
 <IonLabel>
 <IonToggle>
```

check the documentation.

Comment: I got the example from the official Nextjs example repo and they use it like that But I did try it with normal divs and it didn't fix my issue